# Can i add custom code in Source, Header from function.php?

Tags: plugins, php

there are many plugins that do some job but can i add custom code for example: `<link href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Buhehe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">    </head>` 
from Function.php?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
add_action('wp_head',function() {
  echo 'your html here';
});
```

However your `.ico` file should be put in a place it can't be purposely or accidentally deleted, like your theme folder beside your functions.php. Once done you can then use the following to construct the URL:

```
add_action('wp_head',function() {
  echo '<link href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/Buhehe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">';
});
```

Note if you already have a `shortcut icon` in the source code, the browser will pick whichever one its designed to pick (first or last).

Comment: thanks what if i want to add in body or footer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add any code to head tag with the wp_head hook

```
function hook_link() {
    ?>
        <link href="http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Buhehe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to experiment, put code given below inside enqueue style function in your functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style('identifier_for_your_file', 'http://buhehe.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Buhehe.ico');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_shortcut_icon_func' );

function my_shortcut_icon_func() {
  echo '<link href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/Buhehe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">';
}
```

Add the above in your theme's functions.php file